# Windows gone after update of mac OS

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, startup

So I had 2 OS's on my MacBook Pro, one partition was Mac and the other one was Windows 7. After I updated my Mac OS, my Windows disappeared from 'Startup Disk'

[image: Windows disk gone.]

When I open 'Disk Utility' my Windows disk is named 'Untitled', I tried mounting it but the button 'Mount' doesn't work I also tried downloading other programs such as NTFS-3G, Tuxera and others but the 'Mount' button doesn't work on them either.

[image: Windows disk named 'Untitled'. Button 'Mount' does nothing. ']

I'm not really good at computer stuff, thats why I'm here. If someone knows how to make my Windows OS work again or at least retrieve important files from the partition.

Please tell me what to do, because I'm hopelessly trying to find information googling my problem.

Comment: Did you try Recovery Mode? Access it from Command+R. You can also try to do a First Aid.

Comment: I didn't try Recovery Mode. I can't do First Aid because i can't even press the button.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the untitled volumen in Disk Utility. 
See if it offers "mount".
If it is NTFS formatted (which it appears it is), Mac OS should be able to read it (i.e. copy/recover data from it).

Another option:

Boot from a Windows 7 CD.
Then choose "Repair".
See if it finds any Windows to repair (e.g. offering c:\WINDOWS).
If so, try a startup repair from the given options.
(If it is not showing a Windows that it can try to repair, do nothing).

Comment: I tried the first option, didn't work, same as "Mount" button. How do i boot from a Windows 7 CD if i never had one? I installed Windows with Flash Drive, i never had original disk of Windows 7, do i insert Flash Drive with Windows files in it and then Boot? I don't understand the meaning of booting from a Flash Drive or Windows 7 CD as you said.

Comment: If you have Windows installation medium (I was assuming CD, but flash drive could be as well) you can start the computer from it.  Rather than doing an installation from it (I *strongly* advise not doing that) it also offers repair functions.  Put the flash drive in a slot, restart the Mac, then when you hear the boot-chime, hold down the Alt key.  The Mac won't boot normally, but will offer you all drives from which you could boot, among them should be your flash drive.  Try to select that and see if it offers repair options.  If in doubt, try to find someone who can assist with it.

Comment: +1 for poster being so old-school that he still assumes operating systems are available on CD :-)